# React navigation clearing out data when stored in AsyncStorage - How to view data?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, asyncstorage

I'm using react navigation bottom tab and when I have data stored in my AsyncStorage, the data comes out to be empty when I go into this SavedData component. In the console, if I `showAsyncStorageContentInDev()`, it shows that I do indeed have the key `@storage_key`. But when I console log out the data, its always empty. Does it have to do with something with react navigation bottom tab that empty's out the data?

Or how do I view the data when user tabs into this component?

```
const SavedData = (props) => {
  const [getData, setData] = useState([]);

  const getKeyInfo = async () => {
    try {
      const storedData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key');
      setData(JSON.parse(storedData))
      console.log('saved',getData);
    } catch (e) {
      // saving error
    }
    console.log(getData);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(getData);
    getKeyInfo();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        {getData.map((i, index) => (
          <View key={i.id.toString()}>
            <Data uri={i.uri} />
          </View>
        ))}
        ;
      </Text>
    </View>
  );

};

export default SavedExercise;
```

Comment: Check if you got mistake with `storage_Key` or `storage_key `

Comment: no, i know the k is capitalized on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever try pass `getData` into the second argument of useEffect to notify for Component re-render when state change:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(getData);
    getKeyInfo();
}, [getData]); // Here
```

Comment: For some reason, it keeps updating and doesn't stop. any idea why?